# send to google analytics ecommerce order refund

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying with GA Ecommerce API send order refund.
My refund got to server successfully, but refund amount is always twice greater than the ordering.

Example:
Order price: 20 Euro

Refund amount: 40 Euro

What am I doing wrong?

My parameter:

```
 [t] => pageview
 [ti] => demo001
 [pa] => refund
 [v] => 1
 [dh] => mypage.com
 [dl] => http://mypage.com/ga/
 [dr] => 
 [uip] => 127.0.0.1
 [tid] => UA-XXXXXX-1
 [cid] => XXXXXXXX
```

Server url: http://www.google-analytics.com/collect

Comment: Are you looking to refund an entire transaction, or just one product ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#enhancedecom))? Also, are those all of your parameters?

Comment: Yeah, could you post the whole request?

Comment: Andy>Thanks for documentation, i will check it. I need full service - refund order with all products and refund one product from order (both options).